# Save img with UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using UIImagePickerController for bring images from the photo library,

i found this method for saving the uiimage as png or jpeg:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    // Create paths to output images
    NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
    NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];

    // Write a UIImage to JPEG with minimum compression (best quality)
    // The value 'image' must be a UIImage object
    // The value '1.0' represents image compression quality as value from 0.0 to 1.0
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

    // Write image to PNG
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(<#UIImage *image#>) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

    // Let's check to see if files were successfully written...

    // Create file manager
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Point to Document directory
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    // Write out the contents of home directory to console
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);

    [picker release];
}
```

the problem is that the file in png is 6.4 mb and in jpeg 3.2 mb, there is a way for saving the image file in smaller size then this?

Comment: The short answer is yes it is possible to reduce the size. But it is a pretty elaborate process, I am unfortunately not home now so I can't provide more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could resize image and save image in smaller size.

Here is an example of method for resizing image:

```
- (void)setThumbnailFromImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize origImageSize = [image size];

    CGRect newRect;
    newRect.origin = CGPointZero;
    newRect.size = CGSizeMake(40, 40);

    // how do we scale the image?
    float ratio = MAX(newRect.size.width/origImageSize.width,
                      newRect.size.height/origImageSize.height);

    // create a bitmap image context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newRect.size);

    // Round the corners
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:newRect
                                                    cornerRadius:5.0];
    [path addClip];

    // into what rectangle shall I composite the image?
    CGRect projectRect;
    projectRect.size.width = ratio * origImageSize.width;
    projectRect.size.height = ratio * origImageSize.height;
    projectRect.origin.x = (newRect.size.width - projectRect.size.width) / 2.0;
    projectRect.origin.y = (newRect.size.height - projectRect.size.height) / 2.0;

    // draw the image on it
    [image drawInRect:projectRect];

    // get the image from the image context, retain it as our thumbnail
    UIImage *small = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self setThumbnail:small];

    // cleanup image contex resources, we're done
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Hope this will help you! =)

Comment: This unfortunately does not take into account the image orientation which will likely change during the resize process. And be careful MTA as this will also round the corners of the image!!!

Answer (score 1):

Image returns from camera has 1200*1600 pixal resolution and one pixel is represented by 4 byte. only option  to decrease the memory sizeis the resize Image and then compress image in to JPEG or PNG. You can use below method to resize the Image

```
    + (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
               scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return newImage;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can decrease the size of the image by decresing its size**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],.5);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
CGSize size=CGSizeMake(150,150);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

imgView.image =scaledImage; // setting this image imgView"Its a image view" on my view
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way is to save it as **JPEG and reduce the quality**. You set it to 1.0, which results in 3.2 MB, but in my experience a JPEG quality of **0.3** is sufficient for most tasks - you can even read the text in a photo of a newspaper article written with 0.3 quality. The size then is about 700K.

For resizing you should have a look at this excellent article:

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/